# I can't get my Button widget to do anything

Tags: java, android-widget

I'm new at this android stuff and trying to teach myself the language and I'm running into a brick wall here.

I'm trying to program a really simple widge that is just a button. When the button is pressed the phone goes to silent mode. Unfortunately, the onlky thing that I am able to program the button do is pop a toast message.

Can someone please advise me on my errors. Thanks a bunch in advance. Here is my code:

```
package com.DoNotDisturb.widget;

import com.DoNotDisturb.widget.R;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DoNotDisturbWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

        Intent active = new Intent(context, DoNotDisturbWidget.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);

        active.putExtra("msg", "Phone is silent");

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        } else {
            // check, if our Action was called
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
                String msg = "null";
                try {
                    msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification noty = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Do Not Disturb Feature Activated", System.currentTimeMillis());

                noty.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Notice", msg, contentIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(1, noty);

            } else {
                // do nothing
            }

            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

    private AudioManager getSystemService(String audioService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: use getBroadcast instead of getActivity